# Retrieving resources of JWT-authenticated user Spring Boot Java

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java Spring Boot Rest-API which is authenticated using JWT-tokens. Currently the API only contains Users and CashflowCategories. An user can have many CashflowCategories.

When the user makes a request to `GET /cashflowcategories` I want the API to return all the CashflowCategories of that user. Currently I have implemented that this way:

1. User makes GET request with JWT-token authorization.
2. CashflowCategoryController checks if user is authenticated and then retrieves the userId by resolving the claim of the request.
3. Service + Repository get called to retrieve CashflowCategories of this user.

The function in my controller:

```
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCashflowCategoriesByUserId(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            Claims claims = jwtUtil.resolveClaims(request);
            Integer userId = (Integer) claims.get("id");
            
            Collection<CashflowCategory> cashflowCategories = cashflowCategoryService.getCashflowCategoriesByUserId(userId);
            
            return ResponseEntity.ok(cashflowCategories);
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a better way. With this approach I have to use `if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {...}` and `Claims claims = jwtUtil.resolveClaims(request) ...;` in each Controller-function.

**Other relevant files.**

CashflowCategoryController.java

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;

import com.example.demo.auth.JwtUtil;
import com.example.demo.domain.model.CashflowCategory;
import com.example.demo.domain.model.User;
import com.example.demo.domain.model.request.UserAuthRequest;
import com.example.demo.domain.model.response.UserAuthResponse;
import com.example.demo.services.CashflowCategoryService;
import com.example.demo.services.UserService;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cashflowcategories")
public class CashflowCategoryController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CashflowCategoryService cashflowCategoryService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCashflowCategoriesByUserId(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            Claims claims = jwtUtil.resolveClaims(request);
            Integer userId = (Integer) claims.get("id");
            
            Collection<CashflowCategory> cashflowCategories = cashflowCategoryService.getCashflowCategoriesByUserId(userId);
            
            return ResponseEntity.ok(cashflowCategories);
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }
}
```

CashflowCategoryService.java

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.auth.UserResourceValidator;
import com.example.demo.domain.model.CashflowCategory;
import com.example.demo.domain.model.User;
import com.example.demo.repositories.CashflowCategoryRepository;
import com.example.demo.repositories.UserRepository;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CashflowCategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private CashflowCategoryRepository cashflowCategoryRepository;
    
    public CashflowCategory createCashflowCategory(CashflowCategory cashflowCategory) {
        return cashflowCategoryRepository.save(cashflowCategory);
    }
    
    public Collection<CashflowCategory> getCashflowCategoriesByUserId(Integer userId) {
        return cashflowCategoryRepository.findByUserId(userId);
    }
}
```

CashflowCategoryRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.domain.model.CashflowCategory;
import com.example.demo.domain.model.User;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface CashflowCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<CashflowCategory, Integer> {
     public Collection<CashflowCategory> findByUserId(Integer userId);
}
```

JwtUtil.java

```
package com.example.demo.auth;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demo.domain.model.User;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtParser;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    //@Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private final String secret_key = "secret123";
    
    
    private long lifeTime = 60*60*1000;
    
    private final JwtParser jwtParser;

    private final String TOKEN_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    
    public JwtUtil(){
        this.jwtParser = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret_key);
    }

    public String createToken(User user) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(user.getName());
        claims.put("id", user.getId());
        Date tokenCreateTime = new Date();
        Date tokenValidity = new Date(tokenCreateTime.getTime() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(lifeTime));
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setExpiration(tokenValidity)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret_key)
                .compact();
    }
    
    private Claims parseJwtClaims(String token) {
        return jwtParser.parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }
    
    public Claims resolveClaims(HttpServletRequest req) {
        try {
            String token = resolveToken(req);
            if (token != null) {
                return parseJwtClaims(token);
            }
            return null;
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            req.setAttribute("expired", ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            req.setAttribute("invalid", ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    
    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(TOKEN_HEADER);
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            return bearerToken.substring(TOKEN_PREFIX.length());
        }
        
        return null;
    }

    public boolean validateClaims(Claims claims) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            return claims.getExpiration().after(new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.example.demo.domain.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_id_seq", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String pass;
    
    @OneToMany
    Collection<CashflowCategory> cashflowCategories;
    
    User() {}
    
    User(String name, String pass) {
        this.name = name;
        
        String hash = BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());
        this.pass = hash;
    }
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        String hash = BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());
        this.pass = hash;
    }
    
    public String getPass() {
        return this.pass;
    }
}
```

CashflowCategory.java

````
package com.example.demo.domain.model;

import com.example.demo.domain.types.CashflowType;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cashflow_categories")
public class CashflowCategory {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cashflow_categories_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cashflow_categories_id_seq", sequenceName = "cashflow_categories_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;
    private String label;
    private String color;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CashflowType type;
    
    private boolean persistent;
    
    //@Column(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    

    CashflowCategory() {}
    
    CashflowCategory(String label, String color, CashflowType type, boolean persistent, User user) {
        this.label = label;
        this.color = color;
        this.type = type;
        this.persistent = persistent;
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    
    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }
    
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public CashflowType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(CashflowType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isPersistent() {
        return persistent;
    }

    public void setPersistent(boolean persistent) {
        this.persistent = persistent;
    }
    
    
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
}
```
````

Comment: I'm not a full on Spring Boot expert, but I would do two things to help the auth and jwt unpacking:  Use something like `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` annotating the endpoint which will do the check and return 403 if it fails.  Then you can write a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that will unpack the token before the endpoint is called and let you put stuff like `user_id` an object that gets passed in like you pass in `HttpServletRequest`, see example 4.1 here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder .  e.g. make a single field `UserId` class to replace `Version` there